# How to Convert the converted HTML tags back to the actual HTML Content

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm converting the HTML tags to XML using "DBMS_XMLGEN.convert" funciton.
Ex:-

Original HTML Text:-

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;"><FONT color=#000080 size=2><FONT color=#000080 size=2>
```

Converting to XML :-

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.convert('<p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;"><FONT color=#000080 size=2><FONT color=#000080 size=2>') FROM dual
```

OUTPUT:-

```
<p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;FONT color=#000080 size=2&gt;&lt;FONT color=#000080 size=2>;
```

Now I want to convert the above output to actual HTML content.

i.e

```
<p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;FONT color=#000080 size=2&gt;&lt;FONT color=#000080 size=2>;
```

TO

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 0pt;"><FONT color=#000080 size=2><FONT color=#000080 size=2>
```

Please suggest any oracle function is there for this or any alternate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same function, but this time with additional parameter [1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100).

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (
          '<p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0pt;&quot;&gt;&lt;FONT color=#000080 size=2&gt;&lt;FONT color=#000080 size=2>;',
          1)
  FROM DUAL
```